# Find system partition Bash

Tags: bash, shell, android

How can I find system partition in bash? I'm writing a shell script in bash  for Phoenix OS and I'm making a kernel changer script for it. The script should replace 3 things 1) modules folder 2) firmware folder 3) kernel file.

The first two are located in the system folder of the PhoenixOS, but the kernel file is not. We have to mount the partition in a folder for example **ext4** to change kernel file:

```
cd data/media/0
mkdir -m 755 ext4
mount -t ext4 -rw /dev/block/sdaX /data/media/0/ext4
```

X should be replaced with a number of system partition

But there is a problem. I need to identify the `/dev/sda` of the PhoenixOS partition because different users will have different partitions. So my question is how can I identify the `/dev/sda` of the system from a bash script?

I searched the internet and have not found anything related.

Comment: So you want to list the partitions on `/dev/sda`? `fdisk -l /dev/sda` might do the trick

Comment: well i want to identify the the system partition and then run the command of mounting it according to its /dev/sda

Comment: or maybe i can make a command that lists the partitions to the user and ask them to select the system one then the process of mounting will start

Comment: What is the system partition? How do you identify it? What makes it a "system" partition? If you do this manually, how do you figure out which one it is?

Comment: what i mean by system partition? i mean its where **PhoenixOS** is installed 
how do we install PhoenixOS in windows i'm talking about windows because most users install **PhoenixOS** using windows
1) create a ext4 partition
2) Create **PhoenixOS** Folder inside that ext4 partition
3) paste **system.img initrd.img ramdisk.img kernel** in PhoenixOS Folder  4) Create a boot entry for it
but different users have different amount of partitions which mean different /dev/sda
So my question is how to identify /dev/sda Of Phoenix OS partition in its build in terminal which understands bash

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, I don't think that there is an answer *within* `bash`. What you'll probably end up with is an answer using a common command-line tool commonly installed in **Phoenix OS**. I don't use that OS, but let me suggest two common linux tools that might be installed by default in Phoenix OS, and then you can use `bash` to parse the output:

1] `lsblk`

2] `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label`

If you have `lsblk` available, your version may support JSON ouput format (`-J`) or different ascii outputs (see the `man` page).

Comment: Phoenix OS is Based on android x86 project

Comment: ill try your suggestion